# Where is Visual Studio 2012 route table?

Tags: asp.net, routes

I have a question about the default template generated by VS2012. I can see that when I create a new website and choose asp.net webform site, a lot of packages is added. When I run the web page and I can see that all the pages created by default all have friendly urls. For example, http://www.example.com/Contact, http://www.example.com/Account/Login and so on. I want to know where is this route table resided? I want to go and add more url based on my requirements.

Comment: Are you sure that is a WebForm? I thought only MVC templates started with clean urls.

Comment: Yes 100% sure Zerky. Just try to go to File>New Website> Asp.net WebForms Site. It's Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

You should see the routing codefile in your `App_Start` directory. It will include the default routes.

In previous versions, the routing was put into Global.asax.cs, but they moved it in the later versions. Looks like the MVC4 template has the new directory and route files (RouteConfig.cs and WebApiConfig.cs), and the MVC3 template still puts it into Global.asax.cs.

Comment: There is no App_start directory, Joe.

Comment: Which type of web project did you select when you created the project?

Comment: I notice in my Global.asax in the application start, there is RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes). The RegisterRoutes method is not there in the Global.asax. Is it somewhere in the .dll file?

Comment: website project using asp.net web form site.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking you were using MVC - didn't notice your question defined that you were using a "Web Site", which is significantly different from a regular Web Application. Looks like the routing is done in App_Code/RouteConfig, which hooks up some voodoo with `routes.EnableFriendlyUrls();` - no idea what that actually does. My guess would be it just allows you to leave off the `.aspx` in the browser.